# How to prevent classes in jar from overlapping to current project in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven project called A, and it depends on another jar file called B.jar, both A and B.jar has same class but with different version. During maven build that classes in B.jar always overlap in A. What's the way to let maven only takes the classes in A not B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have a real problem of conception about your Maven modules.

A JAR is not designed to exclude some classes when it is used by another JAR.

Why in B JAR, don't you provide a way to choose at runtime the implementation class to use ? 
You can allow it by multiple ways : a property, an interface to implement ,etc....
In this way, you could specify the class to use in the client application.
You should think in terms of API to implement by client classes, not in terms of overwriting classes.

---

It doesn't mean that you cannot do it with Maven but it seems intricate, not natural, error prone and not good designed.
Here's some ideas to solve it with Maven.

You could configure the maven-jar-plugin to specify the class to exclude in the packaged jar :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>a.b.c.MyclassToExclude.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) is the reference documentation.

But by doing it, the class will not be available in the JAR in any case.
It makes the B JAR not working alone if the class to replace is required in `B`.

You could package the JAR with a [specific classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) to avoid this problem.
You would have so the classic jar that contains everything and the jar-for-a that contains everything but this famous duplicate class.

But really, I think that you should really think about your design.